# Trying to install intl extension macOS Catalina and PHP 7.4.10

Tags: php, zip, config, intl

I am trying to install the `zip` and the `intl` extension for `PHP 7.4.10`

I run

```
sudo pecl install intl
```

and then the installation is requesting :

```sh
Specify where ICU libraries and headers can be found [DEFAULT] :
```

then I hit enter and continues but then it shows the next error:

```
configure: error: Package requirements (icu-uc >= 50.1 icu-io icu-i18n) were not met:

No package 'icu-uc' found
No package 'icu-io' found
No package 'icu-i18n' found
```

then I start to look how to install `icu`, I run:

```
brew install icu4c
```

the console shows:

```sh
If you need to have icu4c first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/bin:$PATH"' >> /Users/user/.bash_profile
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/sbin:$PATH"' >> /Users/user/.bash_profile

For compilers to find icu4c you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/icu4c/include"

For pkg-config to find icu4c you may need to set:
  export .bash_profile="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/pkgconfig"
```

I added all the paths to the `.bash_profile` config file and run:

```sh
source .bash_profile
```

at this point I am not sure what todo I am still receiving:

```
== Environment ==
!! php_extension zip !!
[System] must be installed and enabled - The Zip PHP extension is now required by Moodle, info-ZIP binaries or
PclZip library are not used anymore.


!! php_extension intl !!
[System] must be installed and enabled - Intl extension is required to improve internationalization support, such as
locale aware sorting and international domain names.
```

even after run `sudo apachectl restart`

also I have check a lot of guides to install the `zip` extension via `php.ini` adding `extension=zip` but is not working

any help will be appreciated

[UPDATE]I tried to use the fist answer to the post and I got after run all and the last command output was `sudo pecl update-channels && sudo pecl install intl`

```
checking for icu-uc >= 50.1 icu-io icu-i18n... no
configure: error: Package requirements (icu-uc >= 50.1 icu-io icu-i18n) were not met:

No package 'icu-uc' found
No package 'icu-io' found
No package 'icu-i18n' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables ICU_CFLAGS
and ICU_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
ERROR: `/private/tmp/pear/temp/intl/configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/opt/php/bin/php-config --with-icu-dir=/usr/local/opt/icu4c' failed
```

Comment: try the method in the link below:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58386905/2088945

Comment: For me it is not working

Comment: @Thierrydev I tried and it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is icu4c present on your system ? What is the output of:

```
which icu4c
```

If you have no output we can investigate further. A quick look at the [ICU documentation](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/36958) tell us that the library relies on autoconf.

```
brew update

brew install autoconf automake libtool

brew install icu4c
```

Now let's check if icu4c is installed properly

```
which icu4c
```

If at this point you still have no output then it's better to install and compile icu4c from source.Because this library installed via Homebrew could be suffering [from](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/19035) [multiple](https://discourse.brew.sh/t/how-to-fix-broken-link-to-usr-local-opt-icu4c-after-upgrade-update/4923/2) [issues](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/36958).

```
wget https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/releases/download/release-67-1/icu4c-67_1-src.tgz

tar xvfz icu4c-67_1-src.tgz

cd icu/source

./configure --prefix=/usr/local/opt/icu4c/67_1 --enable-icu-config
sudo make && sudo make install
```

Afterwards you can resume

```
sudo pecl update-channels && sudo pecl install intl
```

If you will be asked

> Specify where ICU libraries and headers can be found [DEFAULT] :

The answer is

```
/usr/local/opt/icu4c
```

Comment: No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/intl"

Answer (score 3):

When icu4c is installed with brew, it doesn't copy its files to pkg-config configuration directory.
So, another workaround would be to be to set the PKG_CONFIG_PATH to the folder where the lib is located. Example:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/69.1/lib/pkgconfig/ pkg-config --cflags --libs libsoup-2.4
```