# Error when installing Ckeditor on Symfony 4.3

Tags: symfony, ckeditor

I have a problem when installing CKeditor on Symfony 4.3, it puts me in the console when I enter the command to install the ckeditor bundle:

```
composer require friendsofsymfony / ckeditor-bundle
```

And an error appears and the console answers me:

> Problem 1
>        - Installation request for friendsofsymfony / ckeditor-bundle ^ 2.2 -> satisfiable by friendsofsymfony / ckeditor-bundle [2.2.0].
>        - friendsofsymfony / ckeditor-bundle 2.2.0 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
>
> Installation failed, deleting ./composer.json.
>   Air-de-Clement: $ composer require friendsofsymfony / ckeditor-bundle ^ 5

Comment: please translate your title into english.

Comment: The `the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system` message doesn't clearly respond to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Composer said to you that `the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system`. You need to install it.

You could run `sudo apt-get install php7.VERSION-zip`

Like said [here for linux](http://www.compulsivecoders.com/tech/how-to-install-php-ext-zip-extension/)

Or [here for macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58300437/6410457)

Comment: how can i install PHP ext-zip extension on Mac OS x Catalina?

Comment: Hope this answer will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58300437/6410457