# Laravel installation problems

Tags: php, laravel, macos

I tried to install laravel framework with composer in MacOS

```
composer global require laravel/installer
```

First error message:
Problem 1

```
- Installation request for laravel/installer ^3.1 -> satisfiable by laravel/installer[v3.1.0].
- laravel/installer v3.1.0 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
```

I am  trying to  install php.zip:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.3-zip
```

And I get next error message:

> Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/apt" (-1)

How can I solve this installation error chain?

Comment: Did problem occurs from your apt file manager, did you try `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: @STA I try according your advice. And I got in Terminal:

    sudo: apt-get: command not found

Comment: It should be `sudo apt-get`

Comment: @STA If to put 'space' between atp and -get than Terminal writes:

Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/apt" (-1)

Comment: i think you sould change extenstions part of php.ini

Comment: @Dotizo Please kindly clarify the actions for changing extentions part of php.ini

Comment: There is no space in `apt-get`.

Comment: @kerbh0lz Then Terminal outputs:

command not found

Comment: What OS are you using? `apt` and `apt-get` should be available on Ubuntu/Linux Mint and  other Debian based distros

Comment: @kerbh0lz OS = MacOS

Comment: i uncommented this part in php.ini `extension=fileinfo` , and my problem gone quickly

Comment: No clue about macOS, sorry. See if `apt` is available (`sudo apt install php7.3-zip`) and maybe add a macos tag to the question so others know

Comment: @Dotizo Can't find php.ini to edit it

Comment: For `php.ini` file location type `php --ini` in terminal.

Comment: Btw, `apt-get` is linux' command not macos. Check https://brew.sh for packages installing on macos. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80711/how-to-install-apt-get-or-yum-on-mac-os-x

Comment: Does this answer your question? [install ext-zip for Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58290566/install-ext-zip-for-mac)