# Composer error during a installing new package

Tags: laravel, macos, vue.js, composer-php

I'm working with macOS, Laravel and Vue. My partner is working on Windows and he update the repository installing DomPDF, when I try to do a composer update or composer install I get this error:

`Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.`

Problem 1

```
 - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.14.1 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
 - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.14.0 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
 - Installation request for phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.14 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.14.0, 1.14.1].
```

Comment: I already tried to delete the composer lock file and the package lock json file

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Which parts of that pretty short error message are unclear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your setup.

Long story short, you need to install ext-zip, which is a PHP extension.

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58290566/install-ext-zip-for-mac) will solve your issue.

Try:

```
brew update
brew install php@7.3
brew link php@7.3
```