# Missing ext-zip extension on macOS Big Sur

Tags: php, composer-php, macos-big-sur

I am trying to install a barcode plugin using composer and each time I run the composer command on macOS Big Sur, it gives me the error below

**Problem 1**

```
- phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.0.0, ..., 1.18.0] require ext-zip * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's zip extension.
- Root composer.json requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet * -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.0.0, ..., 1.18.0].
```

I have uncommented out this (extension=php_zip.dll) in the php.ini file and restarted the apache service but still getting same error.

Please any help on how to resolve this

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58290566/install-ext-zip-for-mac

Comment: `php_zip.dll`  is a DLL for windows, not for mac